# CodeIgniter Application Libraries v/s System Libraries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

Im CI new bee. Just went through framework and realize both application and system folder has folder named libraries which contain some classes. I figured it out what their use is, what I didn't understand is why there are two different folders since they both are libraries ?

Any major difference they has that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library folder in system folder is contain built-in library. The library folder in application folder is place where you can put your own library. The controller will default find the library in library folder in system folder, if it doesnt found, the controller then will find in library folder in application folder.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html